# Python Pandas for Selecting Multiple Rows with one row having conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I am selecting two columns from, and also I am utilizing the loc function to get certain rows. My code looks like this:

```
 df[['COLUMN_1', 'COLUMN_2',]].loc[1:205]
```

I am needing to only select values > 35 from 'column_1'

I can do this when I select one column by using this code:

```
df[df["column_1"] > 35
```

However, when selecting multiple columns (my first code example), I am not able to reach a conclusion. I am brand new to Python, so I have a solid understanding of only the foundational syntax.

Comment: `df.loc[lambda df: df["col1"] > 35, ["col1", "col2"]]`

Comment: Why use lambda df?  df.loc[df["col1"] > 35, ["col1", "col2"]] is shorter and seems to be more standard?